# Creating delegates for my Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a container view where the container's view controllers can manipulate button's/labels on the root view controller.

Essentially, I am trying to create a custom navigation bar at the top of my view controller, where the navigation of the container determines the back button's title. The back buttons can pop View Controllers inside my container view.

I am confused as to how I would set up the delegates.

The View Controllers for my container need to be able to listen for when the custom back button is tapped. And I am also trying to set the back button's title depending on which view controller is being presented by my container view. Thank you for any advice.

My hierarchy looks like this.

```
                          Root View Controller -- Custom Navigation Buttons
                                  |
                             Container View
                                  |
                          Navigation Controller
                                  |
                         Custom View Controller
                                  |
                         Custom View Controller
```

Comment: This sounds like you might have an easier time with NSNotificationCenter. It seems like you need more than one object to be aware of your custom viewController's state. NSNotifications are also a pleasure to work with compared to writing individual delegates all the way back to the Root VC. Here's an [NSHipster Article](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have made a tutorial for this: [Custom Navigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLHTKwHnVn8). In the video I am using a UISegmentedController however the same technique is used.

---

I will try and go through step by step how to do this.

Create an NSObject Class and call it ButtonHandler.

Create methods such as

```
//create as many as needed
-(IBAction)handleButton1:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyButtonPressed1" object:self];
}
```

Drag an NSObject onto your Root View Controller and set it's class to ButtonHandler

Control+drag from your buttons in your custom nav to the object and select which method they should use.

In your `viewDidLoad`method of your Root View, add this:

```
//Notify the Root View when the button has been pressed
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeView1:) name:@"notifyButtonPressed1" object:nil];
```

Add as many of these with their own selectors in order to change the views.

Place this code at the bottom of your Root View Class

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

NSNotificationCenter listens for Notifications in your app in order to perform actions. They are really handy and can save a lot of coding, however they are not right for every instance of transitioning.

Add `@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController * content` to your Root View .h file and in your .m file add this method beneath your `viewDidLoad`

```
//SET THE NEW CONTENT INSIDE THE ROOT VIEW
-(void)setContent:(UIViewController *)content
{
    //CHECK FOR EXISTING CONTENT
    if(_content)
    {
        //IF CONTENT EXISTS, REMOVE IT
        [_content.view removeFromSuperview];
        [_content removeFromParentViewController];
    }

    //NOW ADD THE NEW CONTENT AND DISPLAY
    _content = content;
    [self addChildViewController:_content];
    [_content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:_content.view];

}
```

You will need to create your own methods to display and set the content either creating it by code or assigning it.

This is my method for displaying:

```
-(void)changeView1: (id) sender
{
    //create access to the next view
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];

    NSLog(@"Button 1 pressed");

    //set the _content of the declared UIViewController to be the assigned view
    self.content = vc;

    //THIS SETS THE SIZE AND POSITION OF THE NEW CONTENT
    self.content.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 65, 300, 300);

}
```

Comment: Btw, with this method, you do not need to have any embedding

Comment: Thank you for the response. The thing is though is that I want my navigation to be animated and in the same flow as a navigation controller. Could this accomplish that?

Comment: @Andy Yes certainly you can animate the views transition by using  

`    //self.content.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 65, 300, 300);
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.3 animations:^{
        self.content.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 65, 300, 300);;
    }];`

Comment: @Andy did you end up finding a usable answer or did this work how you needed it to?

Comment: NSNotificationCenter was the best way to go about doing my navigation. However I my navigation was slightly different than what you explained. I will mark your answer as correct though since your idea and help got it working form me. Thank you.

Comment: The app is getting crashed at this line  _content = content; 
please suggest why it is crashing . @AppDevGuy

Comment: @AmitThakur - I have no idea. I would recommend asking a question and posting your code. Perhaps I can help that way. If it contains everything, as written above or if you followed the tutorial video, you should be able to get the code working without an issue.