# Switching Between Views with a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

As it is clear from the title, I'm trying to find a way to switch between views using segmented control. Actually, I got something already and it is working. You can find it below:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = sender;
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.currencyContainer.hidden = NO;
            self.goldContainer.hidden = YES;
            self.alarmContainer.hidden = YES;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.currencyContainer.hidden = YES;
            self.goldContainer.hidden = NO;
            self.alarmContainer.hidden = YES;
            break;
        case 2:
            self.currencyContainer.hidden = YES;
            self.goldContainer.hidden = YES;
            self.alarmContainer.hidden = NO;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So, it depends on the principle becoming hidden and visible. I think it is so common to use, because generally people had the solutions in this way, as I searched from the internet. However, I want it to be slightly different. With my code, all the views are loaded at once, but I want to load when just the views come on the screen. If I switch from 0 to 1 index segment, then I want to load 1st view and show on the screen.

How can I manage it?

Thanks.

Comment: So why don't u try to replace child controllers on your view when secgment selected?

[self selectController:YourControllerClass];

And there you can delete visible controller and load new

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to a tutorial I made on how to do this with UISegmentedControl. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered a similar (not the same, but similar result) question here: [How To Switch Views With NSNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505027/creating-delegates-for-my-container-view/29505683#29505683)

Basically you can switch views using NSNotifications. Your fist view will load and using NSNotifications you can send a notification to a custom class that listens and responds by changing the view; when you select an index on the UISegmentControl, your views would change.

It would look like this in your code, in your NSObject Class `ButtonHandler`:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = sender;
    switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyButtonPressed1" object:self];
        break;
        case 1:
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyButtonPressed2" object:self];
        break;
        case 2:
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notifyButtonPressed3" object:self];
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Then simply follow the rest of the code I have set out in the other post.

This is the effect:

[image: Switch Views with NSNotifications]

**UPDATE**

I have created a tutorial on how to do this at this link: [iOS Custom Navigation with UISegmentedControl](https://youtu.be/oLHTKwHnVn8)

To set the view to be the same as the device bound use the following:

```
//this will get the size of your device view 
//and set it to width and height aka w & h
int w = self.view.frame.size.width;
int h = self.view.frame.size.height;

//THIS SETS THE SIZE AND POSITION OF THE NEW CONTENT
self.content.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out. So, when the segment index is changed, notification will send to right class. Notif. will send via [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeView1:) name:@"notifyButtonPressed1" object:nil]; . Also, view classes has to have a method such as your handleButton method. Does it all ?

Comment: @KutayDemireren Yes. NSNotificationCentre uses actions and listeners to perform functions. So you create a function for each call, or in your case you could use just one method with your `case 1: case 2: etc`

Comment: @KutayDemireren see my updated answer. Also, the answer form Bhutan is for swift, not Obj-C, I am sure you're probably aware.

Comment: Well, I didn't try yet but I will try your last suggestion soon. That tutorial looks amazing. Thank you very much! Can't expect much from anyone.

Comment: @KutayDemireren if you need to set the view to fit the screen use the updated code in the answer. Thanks for accept and upvote, much obliged.

Comment: Its nothing comparing to what you have done for me. Thanks again

Comment: @KutayDemireren if you make millions of dollars remember me hahaha ;-)

Comment: hahaha will give you a part of it. Can we start chat, I want to ask you a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `Lazy Stored Properties` something like this :

```
lazy var currencyContainer:UIView = {
     var newCurrencyContainer = UIView()
     // your initialization code
     return newCurrencyContainer
}()
```

A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

OR

By using optional variable like this :

```
var goldContainer:UIView?
```

and later checking

```
if let goldContainer = goldContainer {
     // view is already created
} else {
     // your custom init
     // goldContainer = UIView()
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: so you suggest me to put if statements, inside every if that i already have, am i right?

Comment: I don’t know your complete code and how many times you have used if statements. I just showed you that these approaches may help you. About your query, if you are confident that your optional variable contains a non-nil value, you can force-unwrap its value using !